# how to separate land-use type from rows to columns from one shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, merge, land-use

i am new to using ArcGIS.

i have one shapefile of land-use data (100 rows) that has different land-use areas for each neighborhood (which are 10 neighborhoods), what i want is to have one row for each neighborhood with different column of the land-use area.

Comment: As in a Pivot table? Thwre is a tool for that. What license level do you have?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Are the 10 neighborhoods located in the same land use shapefile, or in a separate shapefile/shapefiles?

Comment: I have tried using merge and dissolve functions but it did not give what i want. yes all the 10 neighborhoods are located in the same land use shapefile.

Comment: Thanks Nadler for suggestion the "Pivot Table", it works good except that i still have the same number of rows. what i did is first covert the Pivot Field which is the "land-use" from numeric to string e.g residential, industrial ..etc. then run the Pivot Table where the input field is the "neighborhood id", the pivot field is the "land-use" and the value field is the "Area" which is the area for each land-use of each neighborhood.

Comment: Use Pivot table in Excel to get what you want. ArcGIS pivot is different

Comment: but i need to do analysis in the ArcGis

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind without reading the details of your question is the Transpose Fields tool. After reading the question, I'd like to see an example of your attribute table. It sounds like you have a 100 row table with two attributes - neighborhood and landuse. And there are multiple rows with the same values in either attribute. The end result you describe is not geometric, but rather summary statistics (as in that's the tool you would use to get the table you want). You'd then join that to a dissolve based on neighborhood name if you wanted geometry.